# Sorting Array By Object's Values

Tags: c#, arrays, list, sorting

I have an object called `RateQuote` that has the following:

- Name
- Term
- Miles

For example:

```
rate  = new RateQuote() {
  Term = 24,
  Miles = 120000,
  Name = '24 mo. / 120000 miles'
}
```

and

```
rate = new RateQuote() {
  Term = 24,
  Miles = 50000,
  Name = '24 mo. / 50000 miles'
}
```

and

```
rate = new RateQuote() {
  Term = 12,
  Miles = 50000,
  Name = '12 mo. / 50000 miles'
}
```

These `RateQuote`'s are getting added to a RateQuote[] object:

```
  public void AddRate(RateQuote rate)
  {
      Rates = Rates.Concat(new RateQuote[] { rate }).ToArray();
  }
```

After they are added by the `.Concat`, how would I sort it? If my code adds the "24 mo. / 120000 miles" first, then the "24 mo. / 50,000 miles" second and then the "12 mo. / 50000 miles" last, I would want it to sort it so that it is in this order:

- 12 mo. / 50000
- 24 mo. / 50000
- 24 mo. / 120000

It should sort by months first, then miles.  I am confused and would appreciate help.  I know there is a `.Sort` function I can use, but not sure how to use it in this context.  Thank you in advance for all of your help.

Comment: Would be much easier to sort before .Concat (using .OrderBy), if possible.  And why wouldn't it be?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx

Comment: It's a very strange way to make dynamic array. Why don't you use `List<RateQuote>`?

Comment: @Dennis, the code I am working with was written by someone else.  It's on my list of things to fix in the future.  My company has a lot of things on our plate and changing this to a List<RateQuote> isn't on the top of the list right now.  I have it on my list of things to fix when I can.  Our code base is large and would take time to change right now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears you want to order first by `Term` and then by `Miles`. Then you can use:

```
var sorted = Rates
               .OrderBy(r=> r.Term)
               .ThenBy(r=> r.Miles)
               .ToArray();
```

Comment: This worked for me.  Simple and sorted my list how it should.

Comment: @Turp, you are welcome, Also consider using `List<RateQuote>` instead of an array. You can always get an array back from the list by calling `ToArray`

Comment: I came into my Developer position with an application that already existed.  I am slowly, but surely, correcting things like this to make our platform faster and enjoyable for all.  This is on my list of things to do, but for now, I just had to sort this list before it was displayed.  Due to compliance issues.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use linq, something like:

```
var orderedRates = rates.GroupBy(rq => rq.Term)
                       .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
                       .SelectMany(g => g.OrderBy(rq => rq.Miles))
                       .ToArray();
```

Comment: this doesn't do what the OP is asking...Sort by Months first then by Miles

Comment: Uh, no. OP said "It should sort by months first, then miles"

Comment: @Harrison : please read the question properly and stop negative voting.

Comment: @FlyingStreudel:  Looks like I didn't look at your answer well enough.  Sorry.  Not sure why I can't change my vote until an edit is made?

Comment: Hmm, I dunno either, I added a ToArray() in the edit

Comment: @FlyingStreudel, This method works as well.  However, to be honest, I am not sure what the difference between yours and Habib's is.  Yours just seems like a lot more code.  Your thoughts on this?

Comment: @Turp I didn't know `ThenBy` was an extension method :)

Comment: @FlyingStreudel -- Got it. If it makes you feel better, I am going to just use yours in my code.  :)  Have a great day!

Comment: This is way complicated code to order an array based on two properties. You are first grouping and then flattening the collection, and that too for no reason. It makes the code hard to read and follow, and should be avoided in production.

Comment: @Turp As much as I like the rep, I've gotta say that you should really use Habib's code as it is more maintainable and more efficient. Can whoever downvoted remove it so I can stay over 2k when I lose the accepted answer? :)

Comment: @FlyingStreudel - Okay, that's very true.  I'll use his code.